# nodenv 環境で yarn はどのようにインストールするべき？

Tags: node.js, npm, nodenv, yarn

nodenv 下の環境で、 yarn をインストールするときには、どのようにインストールするのが正しいのでしょうか？

#### 1. 公式ページの OS 用インストーラからインストール

しかしこれをやると、 yarn は一つだが node 環境が無数にあるという状態になり、いかにもバグりそうな気がします。

#### 2. npm でインストール

https://yarnpkg.com/ja/

公式ページによれば、 npm ダウンロードはおすすめしない、という旨の説明が記述されている上に、 npm で落ちてくる yarn はバージョンがちょっと古い。

#### 3. それ以外の素敵な方法がある

見当が、ちょっとついていないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm i -g yarn` でダウンロードできるバージョンが割と最新版に最近はなっている様子なので、ひとまず自分は

> 2. npm でインストール

で問題なく諸々を回せていることを報告いたします。